# jquery to style div by selecting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3087"></div>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3088"></div>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3088"></div>
```

How to change background-color of above div with value="3087"

I have tried the following jquery code

```
$(".data-list aws-prio-h value["3087"] ").css("background-color","red");
```

not working

Comment: Missing `.` and attribute selector is wrong and remove space in between  -> `$(".data-list.aws-prio-h[value='3087']").css("background-color","red");
`

Comment: that is not the issue

Comment: $(".data-list.aws-prio-h[value=3087]").css("background-color","red");

Comment: @phobia82: not working

Comment: It should be, when you are using 2 classes for the same element in a selector you should join the classes with a . and not a white space

Comment: This is insane, 5 answers, all with the same line just solving the issue. At least, mention why his code is wrong (more than one error in the selector), link to jQuery selector documentation or something.

Comment: @phobia82 I agree. At best this should be closed as a typo with a comment left pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Missing `.` as it is a [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- Attribute selector is wrong, it must be wrapped in `[]` -> [`[Attribute = 'Value']`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- Remove space in between selectors as it is only element, no parent-child hierarchy

```js
$(".data-list.aws-prio-h[value='3087']").css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3087">A</div>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3088">B</div>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3088">C</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for actually explaining the issues and the solution.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer properly, my +1

Comment: Thanks saved my DAY!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have the CSS selector wrong on the jQuery. Try this:

```
$('.data-list.aws-prio-h[value="3087"]').css("background-color","red");
```

This will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.data-list.aws-prio-h[value="3087"]').css("background-color","red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3087">trest</div>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3088">xgdsfg</div>
<div width="30%" height="60%" class="data-list aws-prio-h" style="cursor:pointer;" value="3088">dsgdg</div>
```

Comment: @RJParkh this worked!

Comment: accept the answer by right tick below the answer. :) @MithunS

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.data-list[value="3087"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!